# How to prevent user being directed to loginActivity(MainActivity)from MainMenu

Tags: android, android-activity

I wrote a messaging application which requires an XMPP connection. Everything is ok when user is changing pages inside the application. Everything is also ok when I send a notification to him and he clicks it to come back to my application. But when he tries to come back to my application from his "last applications" page my application redirects him to my login screen. And since he is connected he cannot login again, hence he is stuck in there. How can I redirect someone from his main menu to another screen other than login(I think it sends him to login because its my main activity.) With sending notifications I was easily able to specify the intent target. Here is what I tried in loginActivity.

```
 protected void onRestart() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        boolean loginStatus=prefs.getBoolean("xmpp_logged_in",true);
        if (loginStatus) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ConversationActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }
        super.onRestart();
    }
```

I have a solution but it is not a pretty one. My app follows this screens Login-Show Contacts- Message with a user.
So in Show Contacts I overwrited onBackPressed and made it same with home button. Here is the code

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(setIntent);
    }
```

Comment: use finish() method in onDestroy() method like a splash screen

Comment: You may already know this but my program works when I try to come back after I press home. But it fails when I try to comeback(when it is cancelled with back button)

Comment: When I do that I cant go on from loginActivity to next activity

Comment: Did you already try to check in onResume, if you are connected?
This way you could check every time your MainActivity regains focus if you are connected and you can redirect him to the login or ConversationActivity

Comment: I agree. your edit doesn't look nice. Won't you try adding `finish()` after calling `startActivity` in your `LoginActivity` instead? In that case, there's no need to override your `onBackPressed`

Comment: When I did that it did not change the outcome.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to put your code inside `onResume()` instead of `onRestart()` since it is more reassuring that the lines of codes here are called every time your app gets into foreground state.

Your code seems okay. Can you make sure that you called `apply()` or `commit()` to your `Shared Preference` transaction after successful login?

For instance,

`prefs.edit().putBoolean("xmpp_logged_in", true).commit();`

Comment: I used prints inside the if statement to check the values. Anyway I solved my problem with overwriting onBackPressed() act same with home button.